# Firestore cannot reach backend on Android Jellybean

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am retrieving data from Firestore in my app. The minimum sdk version of the app is 16. It works fine in all versions from Lollipop (tested only on 5.0, 7.0, 8.1 and 9.0). However in Jellybean, I am getting the following error :-

```
[OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

I have defined internet permissions in my manifest too. Can anyone tell me what might be wrong? I am getting the error in android virtual machine running jellybean x86 image by google with google APIs.

Comment: If this is predictable for you with a new emulator image, and you've verified that your emulator has a good internet connection (try to see if Chrome works), the please file a bug report.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Yes, the browser is working, will file the bug.